# Create SharePoint 2010 Wiki Page or Web Part Page in Visual Studio 2010 Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am currently working a SharePoint 2010 project. I will create a full web application and deploy it to the SharePoint 2010. I want to deploy the application as a single step without manually create site page and add the web part online.

I wonder if there any way to create SharePoint 2010 Wiki Page or Web Part Page in Visual Studio 2010 Programmatically and deploy these pages under the /mysite/SitePages/ folder as a default pages?

In case the user doesn't want the default page that I deployed, they can still change the web part online? (This is what I knew, only the pages under SitePages allow user to change the web page. those page deploy under /mysite/_layouts/ folder does not allow user to change the web page)

Is there any way to do, just like use a Module to deploy a master page?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog post that describes how to deploy a populated web part page via a Feature

http://www.binarywave.com/blogs/eshupps/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=56